# Issue while passing arguments in a function

Tags: r

I am trying to create this function using the following code:

```
sss <- function(dsn, vr){
  tt <- fn$sqldf("select vr, count(vr) as cnt from dsn group by 1 order by cnt")
  return(tt)
}

sss(ln0105,c("loantype"))
```

when calling the function, I am getting the following error:

> Error: no such column: vr

Comment: your sql query is looking for a column named 'vr', and your vr variable is not receiving  the desired string ('loantype' as show in the code)

Comment: Thanks, How do I make sure that vr receives the string as required. Sorry, I am a newbie in R

Comment: Try concatenating using the function `paste()`. Or check the package `glue` which is nice for things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `vr` is a character string identifying which column to use, your code is correct except that you must use `$vr` to cause `vr` to be substituted with its value. With just plain `vr` it will think you are looking for a column literally named `vr`.

Note that you can add the `sqldf` argument `verbose=TRUE` in which case it will show the SQL statement actually passed to SQLite after any substitutions are done.

For more examples, see *Example 5. Insert variables* on the [sqldf github home page](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf).

```
sss <- function(dsn, vr) {
  fn$sqldf("select $vr, count($vr) as cnt from dsn group by 1 order by cnt")
}
```

Here is an example using the builtin `mtcars` data frame after making the above correction.

```
sss(mtcars, "cyl")
```

giving:

```
  cyl cnt
1   6   7
2   4  11
3   8  14
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. The solutions provided worked nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are a newbie, let me expand on what was suggested before:

```
vr <- "loantype"
query  <- paste0("select ", vr, ", count(", vr,") as cnt from dsn group by 1 order by cnt")
cat(query)
```

or

```
vr <- "loantype"
query <- glue::glue("select {vr}, count({vr}) as cnt from dsn group by 1 order by cnt")
cat(query)
```